# adding sas data field in data statement

Tags: sas

I never work in sas before, and now I inherit a sas code that I'm having problem modifying. I have a sas data statement that looks like:

```
data newdata;

length field1 $12.
    field2 8.
    field3 $7.
;
format field1 16.;

run;
```

I need to add a data field at the very end so that I can use

```
proc append base = newdata data = /*something*/
```

How would I go about doing this? the data field is in this format

```
ddMMMyy e.g. 02MAR15
```

I have tried

data newdata;

```
length field1 $12.
    field2 8.
    field3 $7.
    field4 date9.
;
format field1 16.;

run;
```

and also

```
data newdata;
format dob date9.;
length field1 $12.
    field2 8.
    field3 $7.
    field4 dob ddmmmyy10.
;
format field1 16.;

run;
```

None seems to work. I can specify string as data type for field4, but it would fail during the append.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that `length` and `format` are two different things.  `date9.` is a format, not a length; numeric variables have length 3 to 8 but nothing beyond that.

If I understand what you're asking, you have a dataset with 3 columns, and another dataset with four columns, and want to append the latter to the former.

If so, your easiest option is to use `if 0 then set`, which takes the structure of the setting dataset and copies it in without copying its data.

```
data have;
  length field1 $12.
    field2 8.
    field3 $7.
  ;

run;


data have2;
  length field1 $12.
    field2 8.
    field3 $7.
    field4 8.
  ;
  format field4 date9.;
run;

data have;
  if 0 then set have2;  *copies structure of have2 onto this data step PDV;
  set have;
run;

proc append base=have data=have2;
run;
```

Although honestly you could just do

```
data want;
  set have have2;
run;
```

Since you're going to reprocess all of `have` either way.

Comment: I would sing Mariah Carey's Hero for you right now!!

Answer (score 0):

why not just use the force option:

```
 proc append base= newdata
             data= something force;
 run;
```